# Is there one liner LINQ construct for creating dictionary by merging two lists and removing duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes, and two collections of each:

```
public class ClassA {
    String key;
    String value;
    // Some other fields specific to ClassA
}

public class ClassB {
    String key;
    String value;
    // Some other fields specific to ClassB
}

List<ClassA> listA;
List<ClassB> listB;
```

I want to build `Dictionary<String, String>` from `key` and `value` from `listA` and `listB` where `value` would be from `listB` if both lists contain object with same `key` but different `value`s.

Now, I have a solution - create `dictionaryA` from `listA`, create `dictionaryB` from `listB`, merge those dictionaries by properly handling duplicates. There are several SO posts explaining how to do just that.

My question is bit more academic - Is there one liner LINQ construct that can do what I want to do?

Comment: `listA.Zip(listB, (a,b) => new KeyValuePair(a,b)).Distinct().ToDictionary( x => x.Key);`

Comment: I fail to see how `Zip` would work at all for the question at hand; as you'll end up with KeyValuePairs of two classes that are already practically KVP's themselves.

Comment: @JohnWu: `zip()` would work if my `listA` contained keys and `listB` contained values. In my case both lists themselves contain KVPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
 var merged =
     listA.Select(b => new { key = b.key, val = b.value })
     .Union(listB.Select(b => new { key = b.key, val = b.value }))
     .ToDictionary(m => m.key, n => n.val);;
```

Please note that this will not handle objects that have the same key but different value.

To deal with duplicates you'd need:

```
 var d = listA.Select(b => new { key = b.key, val = b.value })
              .Union(listB.Select(b => new { key = b.key, val = b.value }))
              .GroupBy(x => x.key)
              .Select(x => x.First())
              .ToDictionary(m => m.key, n => n.val);
```

Please note this keeps only the first record with a given key and records with the same key, but different value are lost.

---

Test code

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<ClassA> listA = new List<ClassA>() { 
        new ClassA() { key = "A", value = "1" }, 
        new ClassA() { key = "B", value = "2" }};
    List<ClassB> listB = new List<ClassB>() { 
        new ClassB() { key = "B", value = "2" }, 
        new ClassB() { key = "C", value = "3" }, 
        new ClassB() { key = "A", value = "4" }};

    var d = (...)

    foreach( var kvp in d ) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value} ");
    }
}
```

Result

```
A: 1
B: 2
C: 3
```

Comment: Your answer with the duplicate handling looks like the closest to answering the question. A couple things: 1) they specified if keys are duplicated, they want the value from B; so instead of `First()` they should be using `Last()`. 2) You could make it even shorter by skipping the second `Select()` and go directly with `.GroupBy(x => x.key).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Last().val)`

Comment: If I want to preserve values from `listB` if there are duplicate keys, then I suppose, I could either (1) use `last()` instead of `first()` (as @NPras suggested) or (2) swap `listB` and `listA` in the expression computing `var d`.